# Convert float to date

Tags: python, pandas

There is a source column of values from Excel that I would like to convert to dates (python).

```py
df['DATE_'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_'], format='%Y%m%d.0')
```

Source column from Excel:

```
'2010-06-16 00:00:00'
```

Unfortunately, system generates the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/103925alf1/PycharmProjects/p03/venv/Include/p03.py", line 5, in <module>
    df['DATE_'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_'], format='%Y%m%d.0')
  File "C:\Users\103925alf1\PycharmProjects\p03\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 728, in to_datetime
    values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
  File "C:\Users\103925alf1\PycharmProjects\p03\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 435, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\103925alf1\PycharmProjects\p03\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 400, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 142, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
ValueError: time data '2010-06-16 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y%m%d.0' (match)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is the date in this format? `'2010-06-16 00:00:00'`. can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: The only place where dates may be stored as floats (OADate) is Excel. Any Excel reader should be able to handle this automatically though. Where did those values come from?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When posting an error like this, please include the full traceback. By skipping out on the end, you're missing a huge part of the information about what is going wrong! Check out this great post on [how to read a python traceback](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/). We need this information in order to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks , my question is updated